# Scheduling downtimes in Nagios - Disable/enable mail notifications (hosts/services)

Tags: linux, nagios

I have 200 servers.What would be the best way to schedule downtimes?
I do not want to do it manually from the Nagios UI.

Example:
 20 servers among the 200 are brought down on the 1st Monday of the month(for two hours),another 20 on the 1st Tuesday of the month and so on.

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Scheduled-Downtime

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way the web UI does it: [submit commands to the Nagios command pipe](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/extcommands.html), via a script.